# wrap script to receive api function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have a script and need to expose functions so that these can be called from the page where the script is pasted.

For instance, the script thescript.js is:

```
console.log('The script has been loaded');

function doThisAPI() {
   console.log('The API function has been called');
}
```

Now, the index.html where the script is placed is something like:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
       var s = document.createElement('script');
       s.async = true; 
       s.src = '//thescript.js';
       var s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s0);

       doThisAPI();

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, under normal circumstances, index.html would display both messages "The script has been loaded" and "The API function has been called".

However, if the script takes a time to load, the `doThisAPI()` call would throw "Uncaught ReferenceError: doThisAPI is not defined".

How would you wrap the script so that API functions will always be executed only after the script has completely loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an eventlistener on script load and call doThisApi from that function.

```
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.async = true; 
   s.src = '//theScript.js';
   var s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

   s.addEventListener('load', function (e) { 
        doThisAPI();
   }, false);

   s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s0);
```

Comment: this works just fine. I wonder how would you make it work so that ths `s.addEventListener('load, function(e) {` is replaced by a variable, for instance `$s.doThisAPI()`.